# Conditional Formatting off two cells

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to build out a simple campaign tracker and I've been running into a few issues with the conditional formatting of Google Sheets.

I need the cells on column C to change color and number format based on the values in columns A & B. For example: columns A & B are labelled "KPI" & "Target KPI". Suppose the KPI is "Click Through Rate", and the Target is .10%, the value in C1 needs to be a % and turn red when LOWER than the Target and green if higher. However, if the KPI is "Cost Per Conversion" the value in C1 needs to be $ and turn red if it is HIGHER than the Target, and green if lower.

NOTE: The red and green are performance indicators which need to change dynamically if the actual is >/< than the KPI.

[A sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4T7uKql55nc8eb9cHPUbPbQMnvwZ3FPJLB9LI0uA0s/edit?usp=sharing) -Note the columns I spoke about are H - J on this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(IFERROR(FILTER(I2, SEARCH("*%*", I2)))*(J2 < I2), 1)
```




```
=IF(IFERROR(FILTER(I2, SEARCH("*%*", I2)))*(J2 > I2), 1)
```




```
=COUNTIF(J2, "<"&I2)
```




```
=COUNTIF(J2, ">"&I2)
```


[image: 0]